# How to include a project to another project in visual studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

In my visual c++ project i include some codes of other projects.I got confused about how to do next step.Should i add projects or reference project.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly add another project to current solution.

From Visual studio -----> File->Add->Existing Project..